# Pass list of integers to python subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to start a subprocess in python using the subprocess module with this code

```
command = ['python', 'modified_detect.py', '--source', '../frames/', '--weights', weights_file,
           '--originalName', name_of_video, '--directory' '--device', '0',
           '--classes', '0 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 77', '--nosave']

os.chdir('../yolov5/')
subprocess.check_call(command)
```

The problem is that the script I am trying to use gives an error since the value of the `classes` parameter is not a list of integers but a string. Is it possible to pass a list of integers to check_call?

Comment: In which sense it gives an error? Could you post this error?

Comment: A string is the *only* thing you can pass to another process. It's that process's job to parse the string into whatever data type it needs. That's why things like JSON exist: a string-based data-interchange language to communicate data structures across process boundaries.

Comment: You don't *have* to use JSON, but it's still the script's job to do something like `[int(x) for x in args.classes.split()]` to get the list of `int` values it wants from a string argument like `args.classes`.

Comment: Thank you, I solved modifying the script with a solution similar to the one suggested by @chepner